# Magento - Can't Reindex Product Prices

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, reindex

strong textI was trying to add new products to my store but they weren't showing up. I did everything I could but when trying to reindex all the data, the product prices generated an error. I got the "There was a problem with reindexing process." I tried deleting var/cache and var/locks(but i can't actually seem to empty /cache - i don't know if it should be like this). The output I got from the reindex is as follows:

> Product Prices index process unknown error: exception 'PDOException'
>   with message 'SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column
>   list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1' in
>   /chroot/home/xsmokeco/xsmoke.com/html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
>   Stack trace:
>
> 0
>   /chroot/home/xsmokeco/xsmoke.com/html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228):
>   PDOStatement->execute(Array)
>
> 1
>   /chroot/home/xsmokeco/xsmoke.com/html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110):
>   Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
>
> 2
>   /chroot/home/xsmokeco/xsmoke.com/html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300):
>   Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
>
> 3
>   /chroot/home/xsmokeco/xsmoke.com/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479):
>   Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
>
> 4
>   /chroot/home/xsmokeco/xsmoke.com/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
>
> 5
>   /chroot/home/xsmokeco/xsmoke.com/html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
>
> 6
>   /chroot/home/xsmokeco/xsmoke.com/html/app/code/local/Innoexts/StorePricing/Model/Mysql4/Downloadable/Indexer/Price.php(125):
>   Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...')
>
> 7
>   /chroot/home/xsmokeco/xsmoke.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Model/Resource/Indexer/Price.php(47):
>   Innoexts_StorePricing_Model_Mysql4_Downloadable_Indexer_Price->_prepareFinalPriceData()
>
> 8
>   /chroot/home/xsmokeco/xsmoke.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price.php(385):
>   Mage_Downloadable_Model_Resource_Indexer_Price->reindexAll()
>
> 9
>   /chroot/home/xsmokeco/xsmoke.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(143):
>   Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price->reindexAll()
>
> 10
>   /chroot/home/xsmokeco/xsmoke.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(209):
>   Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
>
> 11
>   /chroot/home/xsmokeco/xsmoke.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(255):
>   Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
>
> 12 /chroot/home/xsmokeco/xsmoke.com/html/shell/indexer.php(158):
>   Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
>
> 13 /chroot/home/xsmokeco/xsmoke.com/html/shell/indexer.php(198):
>   Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
>
> 14 {main}
>
> Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136
>   Column count doesn't match value count at row 1' in
>   /chroot/home/xsmokeco/xsmoke.com/html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234
>   Stack trace:
>
> 0
>   /chroot/home/xsmokeco/xsmoke.com/html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110):
>   Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
>
> 1
>   /chroot/home/xsmokeco/xsmoke.com/html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300):
>   Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
>
> 2
>   /chroot/home/xsmokeco/xsmoke.com/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479):
>   Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
>
> 3
>   /chroot/home/xsmokeco/xsmoke.com/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
>
> 4
>   /chroot/home/xsmokeco/xsmoke.com/html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
>
> 5
>   /chroot/home/xsmokeco/xsmoke.com/html/app/code/local/Innoexts/StorePricing/Model/Mysql4/Downloadable/Indexer/Price.php(125):
>   Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...')
>
> 6
>   /chroot/home/xsmokeco/xsmoke.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Model/Resource/Indexer/Price.php(47):
>   Innoexts_StorePricing_Model_Mysql4_Downloadable_Indexer_Price->_prepareFinalPriceData()
>
> 7
>   /chroot/home/xsmokeco/xsmoke.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price.php(385):
>   Mage_Downloadable_Model_Resource_Indexer_Price->reindexAll()
>
> 8
>   /chroot/home/xsmokeco/xsmoke.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(143):
>   Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price->reindexAll()
>
> 9
>   /chroot/home/xsmokeco/xsmoke.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(209):
>   Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
>
> 10
>   /chroot/home/xsmokeco/xsmoke.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(255):
>   Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
>
> 11 /chroot/home/xsmokeco/xsmoke.com/html/shell/indexer.php(158):
>   Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
>
> 12 /chroot/home/xsmokeco/xsmoke.com/html/shell/indexer.php(198):
>   Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
>
> 13 {main}

I am kinda afraid to alter anything in the database, therefore I wanted to ask here for some help. I am using magento 1.7, I never updated it.Thanks in advance

Comment: I recommend as a first step, backing up your database completely.

Comment: Have you tried disabling/removing the `Innoexts/StorePricing` extension?  I noticed in the stack trace that it's altering the some of the Insert queries, which could be the cause.

Answer (score 1):

I got the problem like this it comes from an extension.Maybe you should try Axel method.Backup and uninstall innotext extension and try to reindex again.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve upgraded a couple of Magento CE (1.4) to Magento EE (1.11) using the traditional (and effective) way. But I found that there was an important issue when reindexing prices that prevented Magento from doing it.

Reading this post on Magento Boards I found that the problem (in my case) was related to an error with the catalog_product_entity_tier_price table where some of the entries were related to products that didn’t exist anymore. This was the actual error and when trying to reindex product prices, Magento would throw this message:

```
There was a problem with reindexing process.
```

How to solve it

So you want to solve this. You have to delete all the entries on the catalog_product_entity_tier_price table that are related to a product that doesn’t exist anymore. You can do it manually or you can use the following script I created. It’s really easy to use.

```
Download the script from here
```

In that file you’ll find:

```
The script: clean_tier_prices.php
A library to connect in a really easy way to the db
```

Follow this steps:

```
Make a copy of your database (just in case)
Uncompress the zip file in your magento base directory
Edit the lib/db.php file and put there your connection settings (db user, user pass and db)
Open the browser and go to http://yourmagentopath.com/clean_tier_prices.php
You’ll see wich references have been deleted from the catalog_product_entity_tier_price table
Try reindexing again in your Magento backoffice
```

Important note: You use this script at your own risk. Make a copy of your database before applying it. If you improve this, please share it with me and the rest of the world!
[download from here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/120126/clean_tier_prices.zip)